# Hosting Service Stack at root

Tags: servicestack

I don't get this "[If you want to host ServiceStack at root path (/), you should use this configuration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice):".

What do you mean by root, in terms of setup of the service.  What's the use case for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceStack's [Hello World example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#rootpath) explains when you want to do this. Basically it's whether you want to host ServiceStack services from the root path, e.g `http://hostname/` or at a sub path instead, e.g: `http://hostname/api/`.

Comment: thanks.  So I posted another question about that hostname/api.  Since our service is outside our MVC project, but I'm putting in that "/api" or whatever in the web.config of my MVC project, how does it even know /api exists if there is no folder within my MVC project named "api"?  It doesn't make sense that I'd have an api folder in my MVC project for the service, as the service interface is a project outside my MVC project.  Or are you saying you would have an api folder in my MVC project and a service reference to my service defined in my ServiceProject?  Maybe that's it.

Comment: so you're saying have a folder called whatever, like api in your MVC project and then location obviously would know about it.  Then in your api folder is the service reference to whatever .net project defines your service..

Comment: FYI, I did also note about the dissappointment in the builds.  Even though I'm still trying to get ServiceStack working for hopes that if I do and I try to redownload v3 at a future date, if it builds I can present the case to use SErviceStack to my boss saying we have more confidence in this framework.  For now I'm still trying to setup a sandbox for ServcieStack and work with it so FYI in case you're confused why I'm giving constructive feedback and also still asking questions and trying to still use SS.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict you don't need to create a folder for this, the `<location/>` just says to proxy all `/api` requests to ServiceStack. Also if you're using MVC, you need to tell MVC to ignore the `/api` routes, and other things. See [Mvc-integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration).